# ACF taxonomies, Custom posts & displaying links in archive.php

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I have several custom post types setup with the option of adding ACF taxonomies.

For instance the custom post type for Main wall and Short wall either have different taxonomies applied lets say Red and Blue.

On these pages I have added category links using the following ACF code...

```
    <?php if( get_field('cats') ): ?>

    <div class="categories toggler">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <?php
        $terms = get_field('cats');
        if ($terms): ?>
        <?php foreach ($terms as $term): ?>

        <a class="btn_alt" href="<?php echo get_term_link($term); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

This creates a series of category buttons that go to [www.domainname.com/category/red_wall](http://www.domainname.com/category/red_wall).

On the Wordpress archive.php page I need to display links to all the posts that have the Red taxonomy applied (even if they are on both the Main wall and Short wall posts.

I am getting some success using get_queried_object() but I can't seem to get all the links to the posts to display.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I found the solution here: https://docs.pluginize.com/article/post-types-in-category-tag-archives/

*Out of the box, WordPress does not include custom post types in the archives for the default categories and tags archives. Because of this, you need to add the post types to the query yourself.
You will add the following snippets to your theme’s functions.php*